# Testrail Bad Request error when using add_run method in API

Tags: json, rest

I'm attempting to use the add_run API method to create new test runs on my testrail server. I am using RESTClient to test the command.

The request is `POST index.php?/api/v2/add_run/1`
(I have a project with id 1)

As request headers I am using `Content-Type: application/json` and `Authorization: Basic USERNAME:PASSWORD_BASE64`

request body is:

```
{
"name":"name",
"suite_id":1
}
```

Upon sending the request, I receive a "400 Bad Request" Response with the error message:
 `{"error":"Content-Type header invalid (use Content-Type: application\/json)"}`

Since I am in fact using `Content-Type: application/json` as a request header I have no idea why I am getting this error or what it means. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

one of the TestRail developers here. It's very likely that you didn't submit the Content-Type header correctly, could you please share the source snippet you used to send this request?

Comment: I have this same problem. And I use https://github.com/gurock/testrail-api/blob/master/python/2.x/testrail.py
here is my code: https://gist.github.com/noisy/10b4940fb796edb19ba5